# Resolve DeclaredType generics of static method call

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm writing an annotation processor which needs to generate code calling a static method such as `Collectors.toList()` (full signature: `public static <I> Collector<I, ?, List<I>> toList()`)

Example input:

```java
class Pojo<X> {
  public @CollectWith("Collectors.toList()") List<Thing<X>> things;
}
```

Snippet of code generated from above:

```java
Collector<Thing<X>, ?, List<Thing<X>>> thingsCollector = Collectors.toList();
```

- The base return type of the method-call is always `Collector<T,A,R>`
- From the calling context, the code knows `R` (above it is `List<Thing<X>>`)
- Type-variables `T` and `A` (and `I`) are not known

Pieces in the puzzle

```java
// Lookup specified Collector method
TypeElement collectors = elements.getTypeElement("java.util.stream.Collectors");
ExecutableElement toListMethod = findMethod(collectors, "toList"); 
DeclaredType toListMethodReturnType = (DeclaredType)toListMethod.getReturnType(); // java.util.stream.Collector<T,?,java.util.List<T>>

// R is already known.
DeclaredType R = ... // java.util.List<Thing<X>>
```

Q: Is there any code which resolves the missing type-variables and can compute the `DeclaredType` of `thingsCollector` to be `Collector<Thing<X>, ?, List<Thing<X>>>`.

Comment: I don't understand, what are you trying to get, where are you failing? Could you please explain

Comment: Given we know R, how do we determine I (or <T,A,R>)

Comment: What do you mean `R`? I see `r` in your APT code, but `returnType` is `java.util.stream.Collector<T,?,java.util.List<T>>` according to the comment - you want `T`? or `List<T>` in this case? But to get to `List<Thing<X>>` you'd need to specialize by specifying what `T` is (`Things<X>`) and then read out the last type param?

Comment: Check [this library](https://github.com/fschopp/java-types). Not sure what features it has, but it's the only thing I've ever encountered that sounds relevant. If I'm not mistaken, a library that works with `java.lang.reflect.Type` (i.e. loaded types) would not be of use, as annotation processors work with `javax.lang.model.type` only (which I understand are type descriptors only, not actual loaded types), right? I think the linked library provides reflection based impl which might allow you to use regular type reflection libs like GenTyRef, but I'm just guessing now.

Comment: Looking into it a bit more, it has `ReflectionTypes#resolveActualTypeArguments` which seems to do exactly what you need. Can't expand this into a proper answer as I'm without a computer right now, that's why I'm posting comments only. Btw, [the related Java issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046109) was closed as _Delivered_ in JDK8, meaning this is already in Java, no need for an external lib, I guess.

Comment: JEP 119 looks to be about exposing existing (1.6) javac `Types` (and `Elements`?) utility class to the runtime code - no use here. The class is certainly full of very good stuff and resolves most type-problems relating to *inheritance* or *ownership*. I can't find a way to get it to provide an answer for the above static invocations where type variables are resolved against the caller